# How to address an array index by a negative offset?

Tags: rust

Say I have something like this:

```rust
let SIZE = 100;
let a = [0; SIZE];
let b = -1;
```

How can I then do something like:

```
a[(SIZE/2)+b];
```

There's a mismatch here between the usize index of the array and the i32 of the negative number being subtracted. Is there a convenient way of indexing through an array also with negative offsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to an `isize` (a signed integer with the same size as a `usize`) first:

```rust
a[((SIZE / 2) as isize + b) as usize]
```

Comment: You need to cast the result back to `usize` to index

Answer (score 3):

Like @Aplet123 answered, you may use casts. But if `b` is always negative, you could save the absolute value and just substact it instead:

```rust
let b = 1;

return a[SIZE/2 - b];
```